# How to read hidden details of output in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 648 variable in my train data set. Upon coding:

```
print(train.isnull().sum())
```

python is spiting output for only first 30 and last 30 variables. I want to know results for all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the values with a loop:

```
data = pd.Series(list(range(100)))
[x for x in data]
```